# Checking for total memory usage in a bash script which spawns other processes

Tags: linux, bash, memory-management

If I have a script which calls other programs, how do I periodically check the memory usage for the script?  I can't just use a loop on pmap or ps using the script's pid since the script spawns other processes (which will have their own pid and memory usages).

Does anyone know a nifty way to get the total memory usage of a script which will take into account all the child processes that the script will spawn too?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the various memory-related files under `/proc/<pid>`...

Comment: @twalberg How it can help?

Comment: Well, for example, `/proc/<pid>/status` and `/proc/<pid>/statm` both contain some detailed statistics about memory usage for a specific process. If you look at values from those files for all the processes you are interested in, and add them up, or average them, you should be able to figure out what you are looking for... This is how `ps` finds its information, but it doesn't have much capability for aggregating the data based on various criteria...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If child processes don‘t have their own child it’s quite easy:

```
$ ps h --ppid "$PID" -o vsz | awk '{ SUM+=$0 }; END { print SUM }'
```

Otherwise you may to rely on process group ID (PGID), but it’s worth to ensure that programs you call from script do not set up their’s own process groups.

```
$ ps h -e -o pgid,vsz | awk -v "PGID=$PID" '$1==PGID { SUM+=$2 }; END { print SUM }'
```

If all children of your script do not belong to the same PGID, we can only loop through processes recursively:

```
$ cat ~/bin/vsztree

#!/bin/bash

declare -i VSZ_TOTAL

vsz() {
    while read PID VSZ; do
        VSZ_TOTAL+=$VSZ
        vsz "$PID"
    done < <(ps --ppid "$1" --format pid,vsz --no-headers)
}

vsz "$1"
echo $VSZ_TOTAL

$ vsztree "$PID"
```

Here `$PID` is a PID of your script. Output is a total virtual memory size in kilobytes.

Comment: In the script you wrote aren't you adding the wrong values? it looks like you're adding the pid numbers, we want to add the RSS values from the ps output correct?

Comment: No, script definitely do not summarize PIDs. If you want `rss` instead of `vsz` – just replace one to another.